# Probationary period : Reciprocal employee rights?

Tags: united-kingdom, probation

I have been given a written offer for a job in the UK which includes the following about a probationary period:

> ...first 6 months of your employment will be a probationary period during which we may cancel your employment at any time subject to 4 weeks prior notice.

And I wonder if this works in both directions. While it's not stated in the contract, under UK employment law **is an employee automatically entitled to the same reciprocal rights as the employer**? Which is to say, **am I allowed to resign at any time in the first 6 months with 4 weeks notice** ?

Comment: As an aside... 4 weeks notice in probation is a huge amount. Most probationary periods are 1 week notice

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of probation that there's NO notice? 4 weeks notice is probably more than you would have after the notice period.

Comment: @Erik Keep in mind that this is in the UK.

Comment: I've cut out your reason for asking about this since it's ultimately irrelevant and would likely have attracted some negative reactions.

Comment: @Lilienthal I somewhat expect UK rules to match NL rules, where probation is "no notice". But they might not be, indeed.

Comment: The UK *legal* position is actually [fairly simple](http://www.acas.org.uk/index.aspx?articleid=4096): no notice up to a month, one week from that to two years, then one week per complete year worked up to 12 weeks.

Comment: @PhilipKendall just a comment on use of terms - thats not the *legal* position, thats the *statutory* position.  The contract of employment can increase that (as your link and answer says). "Legal" and "statutory" give two different impressions.

Comment: To the asker of the question - what does your contract say your notice period is?  It should say - if it doesn't, then the statutory minimum notice period mentioned by @PhilipKendall applies.  In the UK, a months notice (or four weeks, depending on your pay periods) is pretty standard, while a longer notice period is usually reserved for important employees, and usually comes with additional benefits.

Answer (score 7):

Unless it is otherwise specified by your contract, you need give [no notice until you've worked there a month, and one week's notice after that](http://www.acas.org.uk/index.aspx?articleid=4096):

> Employees must give their employer a minimum of one week's notice once they have worked for one month. This minimum is unaffected by longer service.

However, there almost certainly is a longer period specified in your contract.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not automatically entitled to reciprocal rights.

But it seems that in this contract *your* requirements for giving notice are not mentioned at all, and that means the statutory requirements (set in law) apply. And they say no notice period for you in the first month, and one week notice after that. So you are actually better off that way.